# Get tuple value by index in c#

Tags: c#

I have a question, I have a simple named tuple and a configuration for with tuple value in 8 cases I should use, but by index so it would look like:

```
    private int[] delayParametersIndexSetup = new int[] {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 };
    private (int delayWheel, int delayDiag) delayParameters = (1, 500);
```

In other words, when I iterate delayParametersIndexSetup I want a value of tuple that is represented by this index something like:

```
   foreach (var index in delayParametersIndexSetup)
   {
       var value = this.delayParameters.ToTuple()[index];
   }
```

and I know I can use Item1, Item2 etc, but i want this to be more flexible without using case statement.

I read that i can use ITuple (item[x] property as it stands in documentation) but my VS this type can not be found.

I this possible?

Comment: I may be confused here, but why are you trying to use a tuple as a collection? Isn't a tuple a key/value store? Like a dictionary

Comment: @MarkDavies No, a tuple is not a key/value store. `Item1` of a tuple is no more significant than `Item2`. The OP wants to dynamically return `Item1` or `Item2` from a tuple based on external data.

Comment: if you do not want to use a case statement. best bet is to try use reflection to call ItemX members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ValueTuple` implements [`ITuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple?view=netframework-4.8) explicitly, so you can do:

```
int value = (int)((ITuple)this.delayParameters)[index];
```

**However**, this will incur two boxing operations: first the tuple as a whole as boxed (as it's cast to `ITuple`), and then the specific tuple member is boxed. Therefore this is probably a **bad idea**!

You'd probably be better off replacing the tuple with an array, or perhaps a custom object like this:

```
public struct DelayParameters
{
    public int DelayWheel { get; }
    public int DelayDiag { get; }

    public int this[int index] => index switch
    {
        0 => DelayWheel,
        1 => DelayDiag,
        _ => throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(nameof(index)),
    };

    public DelayParameters(int delayWheel, int delayDiag) => 
        (DelayWheel, DelayDiag) = (delayWheel, delayDiag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It explicitly implements the ITuple interface, which means you need to convert to ITuple first.

```
private int[] delayParametersIndexSetup = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 };
private (int delayWheel, int delayDiag) delayParameters = (1, 500);

public void Go()
{
    foreach (var index in delayParametersIndexSetup)
    {
        ITuple value = delayParameters;
        var v = value[index];
        Console.WriteLine(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A tuple doesn't seem like the type that's suited for the task, as I understood it at least.

Here are some other ideas.

## A. Dictionary

You could use a dictionary for this task.

```
private int[] delayParametersIndexSetup = new int[] {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 };
private Dictionary<int, int> delayParameters = new Dictionary<int, int>()
{
    { 0, 1 },
    { 1, 500 }
};

(...)

foreach (var index in delayParametersIndexSetup)
{
    var value = this.delayParameters[index];
}
```

You could store the value and the name with

```
private Dictionary<int, (string Name, int Delay)> delayParameters = new Dictionary<int, (string Name, int Delay)>()
{
    { 0, ("Wheel", 1) },
    { 1, ("Diag", 500) }
};
```

## B. Array - contiguous

If the values are contiguous, a list or an array could be OK too.

```
private int[] delayParametersIndexSetup = new int[] {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 };
private int[] delayParameters = new int[]{1,500};

(...)
foreach (var index in delayParametersIndexSetup)
{
   var value = delayParameters[index];
}
```

## C. Array/List + Linq

You could also store index, name, and value in an array or list.

```
var delayParametersIndexSetup = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 };
var delayParameters = new List<(int Index, string Name, int Delay)>() {
    (0, "Wheel", 1),
    (1, "Diag", 500)
};
foreach (var index in delayParametersIndexSetup)
{
    var p = delayParameters.First(p => p.Index == index);
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name}:{p.Delay}");
}
```

```
Diag:500
Wheel:1
Wheel:1
Diag:500
Diag:500
Wheel:1
Wheel:1
Diag:500
```